# regex lookbehind if matches exclude entire lane

Tags: python, regex, negative-lookbehind

I am trying to match single character `]` only if `[!` is not ahead.

###### Regex:

```
(?!(?:\[\!.*))\]
```

###### Expected Result:

```
_dynamic_text_[!_dynamic_text_]_dynamic_text_

_dynamic_text__dynamic_text_]_dynamic_text_
                            ↑
```

##### Current Result

```
_dynamic_text_[!_dynamic_text_]_dynamic_text_
                              ↑
_dynamic_text__dynamic_text_]_dynamic_text_
                            ↑
```

https://regex101.com/r/IIzoX5/1

I have consulted several reference sources, but I am still encountering difficulties in finding out how to accomplish this task.

Would you be able to offer me some guidance or advice?

Comment: Why not use `if '[!' not in text: ....`? What exactly are you trying to achieve? What are you going to do with a `]` that has no `[!` earlier in this string?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes, you are right. But this is the simplified part of the whole. I want to know how can I implement this logic "exclude if lookbehind matches while in between its not fixed length", so that I can apply to the whole.

Comment: The regex in your link is a negative lookahead and not a negative lookbehind. Also, most regex engines don't allow a non-fixed length lookbehind.

Comment: Do you want `(?<!\[![^]]*)]` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/3CcPUG/1))? Can you `pip install regex` and then use that regex library? Because without it, lookbehinds with variable length patterns won't work as `re` does not support them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex:

```bash
^(?!.*\[!)[^]\n]*]
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/GBeKFM/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?!.*\[!)`: Make sure we don't have `[!` anywhere till end
- `[^]\n]*`: Match 0 or more of any character that is not `]` and not a line break
- `]`: Match a `]`

Comment: thank you very much! may I ask `(?!.*\[!)` why the last `!` doesn't need to escape? I thought that `!` has to escape

Comment: Is it possible to only match `]` not the whole string before it? of course I can encircle it `(\])`

Comment: Python regex doesn't support variable length lookbehind otherwise it would have been possible in C# or Javascript

Comment: Regarding `!`, no it doesn't need to escaped in a regex pattern.

Comment: e.g. `(?<!\[![^\]]*)]` will work in JS, C# and PyPi `regex` module only.

Comment: thank you~, you gave me all things I need to know.